# Rendering files from C++ Node.js addon

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I would like to render files in node.js from C++ addon. 
I want to apply some file processing and render the output to the browser via node.js

Here is my C++ Code

```
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);

    in.seekg (0, in.end);
    int length = in.tellg();
    in.seekg (0, in.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [length];
    in.read (buffer,length);
    in.close();

    return buffer;
```

Following is the V8 code to add bindings for node.js, here **buffer** is the output from the above c++ code.

```
    Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[1]);
    const unsigned argc = 1;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = {Local<Value>::New(String::New(buffer))};
    cb->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

This code works well for normal text files. I'm getting problem when reading text files which are having unicode characters. 
For eg,

Original text file

```
test start
Billél
last
```

When receiving in node, I will get

```
test start
Bill�l
last
```

Similarly when reading a jpg, png files the output file is different than the original file.
Please help.

Comment: What character-encoding is the sending and receiving forms using?

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with this as well.  I found an implementation in the V8 examples from Google.  The example I found that properly handles UTF8 encoded files is found here:

https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/samples/shell.cc#218

I adapted the source to this:

```
const char* ReadFile(const char* fileName, int* fileSize)
{
    // reference to c-string version of file
    char *fileBuffer = 0;

    // attempt to open the file
    FILE* fd = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    // clear file size
    *fileSize = 0;

    // file was valid
    if(fd != 0)
    {
       // get size of file
       fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
       *fileSize = ftell(fd);
       rewind(fd);

       // allocate file buffer for file contents
       fileBuffer = (char*)malloc(*fileSize + 1);
       fileBuffer[*fileSize] = 0;

       // copy file contents
       for (int charCount = 0; charCount < *fileSize;)
       {
           int charRead = static_cast<int>(fread(&fileBuffer[charCount], 1, *fileSize - charCount, fd));
           charCount += charRead;
       }

       // close the file
       fclose(fd);
    }

    return fileBuffer;
}
```

Also, make sure when you create a V8 string that you create a [String::Utf8Value](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1String_1_1Utf8Value.html).

```
String::Utf8Value v8Utf8String(...);
```

Then to use the `String::Utf8Value` as a `char*` use the following function:

https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/samples/shell.cc#91